# How to change @JsonProperty name on the go depending on which API is call?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm encountering an issue with dynamic field name changes during JSON deserialization using Jackson in a Spring Boot application. The field name in the JSON data can change dynamically based on different APIs, and despite trying various approaches, the field name reverts to its original name after using treeToValue of ObjectMapper during deserialization.

Key Information:

I have a Animal class with a inner object Tiger which has field teeth.
I have two API's api1 and api2 if api1 is called in response field teeth should be as it is but if api2 is called in response teeth should be replaced with mouth.
I've tried using @JsonAlias and @JsonProperty annotations, but encountered issues.
The goal is to dynamically modify the field name during deserialization based on different APIs.

I'm seeking advice on how to dynamically change field names during JSON deserialization using Jackson in a Spring Boot application. Despite using various approaches, the field name reverts to its original name after using treeToValue method of ObjectMapper. Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

I tried this approach

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(responseDTO);
    String nestedPropertyName = "teeth";
    String newPropertyName = "mouth";
    if (rootNode.has("tiger") && rootNode.get("tiger").has(nestedPropertyName)) {
      ObjectNode tigerNode = (ObjectNode) rootNode.get("tiger");
      JsonNode nestedPropertyValue =tigerNode.get(nestedPropertyName);
      tigerNode.remove(nestedPropertyName);
      tigerNode.set(newPropertyName, nestedPropertyValue);
    }
    BaseResponseDTO modifiedResponseObject =
        objectMapper.treeToValue(rootNode, Animal.class);
```

I also tried converting object into json string and then replacing the required value and again converting it to object with ObjectMapper but still the field reverted back.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do. Do you want to dynamically change the Tiger class on Runtime? If you call treeToValue with Animal.class you will always get an Animal (or an Exception). You will never have a mouth field inside the modifiedResponseObject, that's just not how Java works.

By the way if you have different Responses for different APIs you should have an Animal class and an AnimalV2 class (or similar).

Comment: @berse2212 Animal class contains a field which i want to change based on the which api is call. Is it possible in java?

Comment: As stated above, no that's not possible. You have to create a second to archive this.